# Tapping textfield in webview app does not show soft keyboard

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

in my webview app some textfields are there in the site,but tapping on it does not show soft keyboard.Some grey colored part is coming in the lower side of the display and looks like the keyboard is hiding behing .please help me to solve this problem.

WebActivity.java

```
package com.example.samworkshops;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    public WebView webview;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://app.samworkshops.org");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: u r checking in emulator or in device?

Comment: hi gave an answer , hope it will work for you

Comment: was it working for you?

Comment: answer is again updated , hope it will work ..please check

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, please see this updated answer

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                v.requestFocusFromTouch(); 

            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

please visit 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189

Comment: please see this updated answer..write ontouch as follows==>public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                v.requestFocusFromTouch(); 

            break;
        }
        return false;
    }